# Python Multiprocessing Processes Go 100% to zero without finishing

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, jupyter-lab

I am running Jupiter notebook to process some huge load on a list of arrays as:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
print("Number of processors: ", mp.cpu_count())

pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
try:
    a_results = pool.map_async(process_each_area, [area for area in areas]).get()
except:
    print(e)
finally:
    pool.close()
```

Each processed area create one result file, which I expect to see once all the processes are done.

On submission, all 96 cpu core get busy and I see 96 new kernels as:
[image]

$ ps -ef|grep ipykernel | wc -l
96

But after some time(80-90 minutes), all the cpu's go back to zero usage, while processes are still alive and not complete. I see then while grep as above. Also, results for all the areas are not created.

My question is:
Why process go idle, but not complete after sometime? How can I debug them? Do we have threaddump in python?

Comment: If you use `for i, result in enumerate(pool.imap(process_each_area, [area for area in areas])): print(i)` to run it, how many iterations does it get before stopping? How many iterations should it run in total?

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually return the result of the coroutine by calling `get()` on each one which runs the function. So instead of

```
try:
    a_results = pool.map_async(process_each_area, [area for area in areas]).get()
except:
    print(e)
finally:
    pool.close()
```

You need to do this:

```
try:
    coroutines = pool.map_async(process_each_area, areas)
    a_results = coroutines.get()
except:
    print(e)
finally:
    pool.close()
```

This way it will tell the `AsyncResult` object to return when the process is done. for more info refer to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.get)

Comment: How is that different from the original? They both call `.get()`.

Comment: @NickODell Because its done in the way the docs show how to call it?

Comment: it's not a coroutine?? It's an `AsyncResult` object.

Comment: its just a variable name what you call has not effect on what it does